# iOS DateFormat with milliseconds and timezone

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to format a date in objective-c for an ios app in this format:

```
2017-02-15T16:32:59.9725843+11:00
```

with no luck. I've tried:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZZZZZ";
```

and

```
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.fffffffZZZZZ";
```

As well as a bunch of other formats for the milliseconds and timezone (I've varied the number of Ss and Zs with no luck. All I get is a nil NSString.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Edit] your question with actual testable code with a real string and a call to `dateFromString:`. And be aware that you need `HH`, not `hh`.

Comment: You can search here http://nsdateformatter.com/ for different time and date format universally provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your your String Time format is 24 hour, so use `HH:mm:ss.` in this place `hh:mm:ss.`

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZZZZZ";
NSDate *getDate  = [formatter dateFromString:@"2017-02-15T16:32:59.9725843+11:00"];

NSLog(@"getDate == %@",getDate);
```

output:

[image: xcode output]

Answer (score 1):

It's .SSS, for millisecond check also this **[Unicode Locale Data Markup Language spec](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns)**

Try this code for milliseconds :

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check [nsdateformatter](http://nsdateformatter.com) and [DataFormatting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
dateformatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZZZZZ";
NSString *currentDate  = [dateformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSLog(@"current Date :%@ ",currentDate);
```

Output:

```
current Date :2017-02-15T11:35:11.7790000+05:30
```